# Writing own jQuery-PHP picture upload utility for site

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

After looking around for weeks and being totally confounded by the tutorials that were already on the books, I have decided to write my own jQuery upload script.  I thought I could get it to work but I am  having issues. I will enumerate them:

On the page that I am writing this for, I have placed a jQuery script that looks a little like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var thumb = $('#thumb');  

  $('#profilepicinput').live('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#registerpt3").ajaxForm({
      target: $('#registerpt3').attr('action')
    }).submit();
  });

  $('#profilepicbutton').change(function(){
    alert("Boy I hate PHP");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "register3.php",
      success: function(msg) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "retrievePic.php",
          success: function(msg) {
            var image = new Image();
            $(image).load(function(){
              console.log("we have uploaded this image");
            }).attr('src', 'images/');
            alert("AJAX Success!");
          },
          error: function(msg) {
            alert(" didn't work");
          }
        });
      },
      error:function(msq){
        alert("didn't work!: " + msg);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This calls the following script which will load a picture into a database:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$email = '';

if (isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) {
  $email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
} else {
  $email = 'dww2@pitt.edu';
}

$link = mysql_connect('censcoredFool.com', 'greetmeet', 'Maverick$41'); 

mysql_select_db(first_1) or die("Opps, You are pretty Got-Damned Stupid!  Did you         realize that?!?!?");

$target = './Uploads/'; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']); 

$ok = 1; 

$path = "uploads/";
$Email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");

if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

  if (strlen($name)) {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if (in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
      if ($size<(1024*1024)) { // Image size max 1 MB
        $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {
          mysql_query("insert into personal_photos      (Email, Pics) values('$email', '$tmp')");
          echo "<img   src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'>";
        } else {
          echo "failed";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Invalid file format..";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Please select image..!";
  }

  exit;
}
```

What I have doesn't even seem to work. I get the success alert, but the picture doesn't even upload.  I am guessing the PHP script ran the whole way through but didn't throw an exception or anything.  How do I get this thing to work?

***UPDATE:  After running Firebug My PHP script isn't getting the Picture***
Not sure why that is.  Need to figure out how the $_File datastructure works.

Comment: awesome error messages. Make sure you don't leave them when you send your code to your client.

Comment: Woops sorry.  Just kidding around with my bro there.

Comment: "After looking around for weeks and being totally confounded by the tutorials that were already on the books, I have decided to write my own jQuery upload script." I'm confused. You couldn't get the tutorials to work, so you decided to write it from scratch? That hardly seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers won't send files via ajax for security purposes. To have a pretend-ajax effect on uploads, you might try the excellent [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), which uses an hidden iframe to do the uploading.

Since this is the only answer so far - and it's also right - allow me to give you some OT advice:

- Most of the people using PHP like PHP (*more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio*). Most of them will take your "PHP Sucks" thing as a pretty pretentious thing to say, since your problem has more to do with a lack of basic knowledge of Ajax and http implementations than it has to do with the language's faults. Thus the lack of answers and the unwelcoming comments.
- Your witty is my distracting: please make the debugging output in the code you post as descriptive as possible - actually, it would be a useful thing to do to simply write descriptive output *anyway* - it's easier to find problems that way, trust me.
- If a form is made of one hundred fields ond only one is relevant, please post the relevant field only.

Comment: Big +1. We already told him about AJAX and files in the last thread but maybe it'll sink in this time.

Comment: @ceejayoz I hope so as well - saw the other post too late. I think the plugin part will do it.

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes JavaScript can't normally get access to the files on your hard drive. That's why AJAX often is not good for uploading. (although this might have changed in up-to-date browsers).

What people have been using for file uploads are:

- iFrame. You need to create invisible iframe and submit a form with your upload form targeting that iframe. Your page will not refresh, and you can even execute some javascript from within that frame.
- Flash. Using flash uploader allows you to send multiple files.

Although, you are probably better of using some of the existing upload libraries / methods. I've wrote [my own uploader](https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Field/upload.php), and it's not an easy task.

Comment: I mean, that's all well and good, but how can I improve my script?

Comment: This isn't a code review forum. You'll need to improve your script by not trying to upload files via AJAX, which **won't work**, as @romaninsh pointed out in his answer.

Comment: I am calling a php function which should upload the file?  Why won't that work?

Comment: Because you're calling that PHP function via JavaScript instead of a normal form POST submission. For security reasons, JavaScript **cannot** access file upload fields in most (all major ones, I believe) browsers. Again, this is in @romaninsh's answer.

Comment: ^^^ what is up with that valumns.com/ajax-upload script... The ajaxupload.js script is no where to be found and I don't have time to decode the rest of his script.